# Select randomly 3 records in a second table

Tags: mysql

Helo everyone.

I'm a beginner in MySQL so i need some help for a request.
For the moment, my request return me the informations of a serie(id,name,description) and the average of note of the serie with this request.

```
SELECT s.* , round( coalesce( avg( note.note ) , 0 ) , 1 ) AS average
FROM serie AS s
LEFT JOIN note ON s.id_serie = note.id_serie
GROUP BY s.id_serie
ORDER BY average DESC
```

And i have this response

```
id_serie    name    annee   description     average 
1           DBZ     1984    test            3.5
2           Bleach  2001    description2    2.0
```

I have one more table that content the genre of the serie. This table have only id_genre and id_serie.

What i'd like to have now is a request that query all the data that i already have + max 3 id_genre of a serie.

```
id_serie    name    annee   description     average    genre1   genre2    genre3
1           DBZ     1984    test            3.5        1        2         9
2           Bleach  2001    description2    2.0        1        NULL      NULL
```

if possible, i'd like too that the genre are select randomly if the serie have more than 3 genre (and never select 2 time the same genre for a serie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.  However, instead of producing three columns, it puts the results in a single column with the values concatenated:

```
SELECT s.* , round( coalesce( avg( n.note ) , 0 ) , 1 ) AS average, g.genres
FROM serie s LEFT JOIN
     note n
     ON s.id_serie = n.id_serie LEFT JOIN
     (select substring_index(group_concat(distinct g.genre order by random()), ',', 3) as genres
      from genre g
      group by g.id_serie
    ) g
    on g.id_serie = s.id_serie
GROUP BY s.id_serie
ORDER BY average DESC
```